# Clicking on labels selects the label text and does not render input:focus event

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Label is not getting associated with the input box on loading the page. When I click on the label field text, it selects the text and does not let the user type. If I click anywhere in the input box where the label text is not present, it seems to be working fine.
If I inspect the input field and change the id of the input fields and the associated label "for" attribute value, it associates the two.

```css
/* Every row containing the input tag and label is relative */

table.inputTypeName td.form-row {
  position: relative;
}


/* This is the stylesheet for the label field */

table.inputTypeName label.form-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 20px;
  color: #999;
  cursor: text;
  transition: all .15s ease-in-out 0s;
}


/* Labels shold float above the input box on input:focus event */

table.inputTypeName input.form-textbox:focus~label.form-label {
  top: -1.5em;
  left: 0;
  font-size: .8em;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!--td contains the input box and it's associated label field-->
<table class="inputTypeName">
  <td class="form-row">
    <input type="text" id="the-input" class="form-textbox" ng-model="TypeName" />
    <label for="the-input" class="form-label">Your Name</label>
  </td>
</table>
```

Clicking on label text doesn't let me type in the input box. Clicking anywhere in the input box where the label text is not present triggers the input:focus event.

Comment: Clicking on label is directing focus to input box,  it seems to be working

Comment: When the HTML is illegal, behavior can be vary by browser. Some browsers will ignore illegal content; others will add the required `<tr>` element.

Comment: @georgeawg - I have added <tr> tag to my code. It doesn't seem to work in my angularjs application, but somehow if I try it on codepen, this code does work.

Comment: Use the Developer Console to inspect the element. Look at the "computed style" tab. Something in your CSS is causing a problem that we can't see.